# Rethinkdb failover cluster with just 2 nodes

Tags: rethinkdb

I would like to setup an IOT reporting database, with failover. The idea is to have a cluster with 2 nodes, one in a datacenter one at home.
If "home" looses internet connection, it continues to operate and upon
online status, "datacenter" would align to offline changes.
Now, I read the rethinkdb docs, that you need at least 3 nodes for a failover to function.
So the question is, is my scenario doable with just 2 nodes, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docu https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/

> ```
> First, start RethinkDB on the first machine:
>
> $ rethinkdb --bind all
>
> Then start RethinkDB on the second machine:
>
> $ rethinkdb --join IP_OF_FIRST_MACHINE:29015 --bind all
> ```

Comment: I did this, you loose writing rights to a table if primary goes down.and you have only three servers = bad.

Comment: the 3 servers are needed so that the cluster can form a consensus by majority voting. Not recommended but you can trick the system by running two rethink instances on your datacenter and one on your home and connect this tree into a cluster.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, however, If the other side fails, (the one with 2 instances), we are back to the same issue...

Comment: that's correct, this only works if you need the fail-over in only one direction - which i thought the case was . Otherwise i don't think there is a solution, you need 3 instances.

Comment: Ok, after consensus, I close this question and possibly move to Couchbase or ArangoDB. Sad, I liked RethinkDB

Comment: Well, sad. Hopefully they going to implement some of the missing features in the upcoming rebirthdb releases.

Comment: Too late, need to progress. Anyone else searching for a substitute, if you do not need graphs, couchbase community is very close with replication features.